# petición POST con parámetros vacíos en express

Tags: nodejs, express, post

Estoy tratando de responder a una petición POST con node express, el problema es que cuándo el cuerpo de la petición está totalmente vacío cuándo intento imprimirla, por que pasará esto? tengo los middleware express.json y express.urlencoded. La petición la estoy probando con POSTMAN, adjunto imágenes del código y de la respuesta para que vean como la imprime vacía.

Este es mi pedazo de código:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const router = express.Router();
const Users = require('../models/users.js');
const server = require('../server.js');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

router.get('/hola', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const users = await Users.getAll();
  res.send(users);

 }catch(e){
  res.send('Ocurrio un error: '+e);
 }

});

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
 console.log('Entró a la petición.');
 console.log('Peticion: ',req.body);
 //req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
 try{
  const result = await Users.insert(req.body);
  res.json(result)
 }catch(e){
  res.send('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario'+e);
  console.log('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario'+e);
 }
});

// router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
//  try {
//   const users = await Users.getAll();
//   res.send(users);

//  }catch(e){
//   res.send('Ocurrio un error: '+e);
//  }

// });

module.exports = router
```

Así configuro el POSTMAN:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la respuesta vacía que obtengo en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes de hacer esta pregunta he leído varios post donde publican el mismo problema, he probado las soluciones que han sugerido pero no me han funcionado, sigue imprimiendo vacío, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: Que versión de express estas usando, has intentado hacer con body-parser?

Comment: Por supuesto que recibes el cuerpo de la solicitud vacío. No estás enviando los datos en el cuerpo sino en la *url*. Si haces un `console.log(req.query);` verás los valores. En Postman debes usar la pestaña `body`, no la pestaña `params`. Saludos

Comment: @Isaac, a partir de Express versión 4.16.0 en adelante, no es necesario instalar `body-parser` como dependencia adicional, ya que Express implementa los métodos de `body-parser` directamente con `express.json()` y `express.urlencoded()`. Más información en la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)

Comment: @MauricioContreras Era eso. req.query sería para peticiones GET y req.body para peticiones POST ? o estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: Por cierto, cuando envías datos usando `body`, asegúrate de enviarlos con la codificación `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Ok amigo, eso hice. No respondiste mi última pregunta.   req.query sería para peticiones GET y req.body para peticiones POST ? Porque es que en la documentación no especifican eso.

Comment: Normalmente las peticiones `GET` se utilizan para solicitar datos al servidor. Si deseas datos específicos o filtrar los resultados por parámetros (color, talla, apellido, etc.) usas los parámetros en la `query` de la solicitud. Las solicitudes `POST` por lo general se usan para enviar datos al servidor, con la intención de crear un nuevo documento o registro en el mismo. Usualmente estos datos son enviados desde un formulario que el usuario llena. Estos datos se envían en el `body` de la solicitud, usualmente cuando se hace `clic` en el botón de enviar del formulario. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Los datos no se envían porque estás utilizando QueryParams, normalmente se utiliza para enviar parametros en un GET y se arma una url como http://myapi.com/backend?**nombre**=juan&**apellido**=perez

En donde nombre y apellido serian los keys.

Para tu caso debes utilizar la sección de Body y enviar la data ya sea por form-data, url-encoded o raw(json).

Para más información te paso la documentación en Postman

[Documentación de Postman para envío de data](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#sending-body-data)